Links(Hyperlinks) inside an svg not working when the svg is placed in an img tag in a Bootstrap 5 Modal
In fact , the pointer doesn't even change its shape when it is hovered over the part containing the hyperlink. When I open the svg file  separately in my browser , the links work alright . Below is the code:
<HTML>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="drawing.svg">
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS


.modal-dialog{
  pointer-events: all !important;
}

As you can see above,  I tried setting pointer-events :all !important;  but that didn't work.

Replace the img element with the object element.

An image (whether SVG or otherwise) is a a static object with no internal functionality. Just use the actual SVG.

Take inspiration from the Native JavaScript <load-file> Web Component I blogged about.

So , anyone trying to use SVG to refer to links (which are inside the svg), do not use <img> tag , use the <object> tag.
Like this :
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="path/to/your/drawing.svg"></object>

Thank you everyone!
